# Is the guitar riff from the chorus of The Rover used in any other songs?

Tags: led-zeppelin, sample

Listening to Led Zeppelin's [*The Rover*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qK_ZtN9K2EM) for the first time, I thought I recognized the guitar riff from the chorus, but I don't know where else I could have heard it. Are there any songs that sample that particular riff, or which have very similar guitar riffs?

(To clarify, I mean the guitar riff that's first heard from around 1:28 to about 1:50.)

Answer (score 6):

The guitar riff/chord structure has hints of Stairway to Heaven, but in a different key

The verse sounds like anything by ZZ Top, with a touch of Rocky Mountain Way, minus the shuffle.

[WhoSampled](http://www.whosampled.com/cover/47286/Dream-Theater-The-Rover-Achilles-Last-Stand-the-Song-Remains-the-Same-Led-Zeppelin-The-Rover/) has it listed as a cover by Dream Theatre, but no instances of it being sampled directly

Comment: Dream Theater finished the "A Change of Seasons" disc with live covers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Change_of_Seasons